# What is the difference between a general and an ordinary sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

We defined a bounded sequence as

> If $\exists_y \: x_j \rightarrow y$, then $x_j$ is bounded in the case of ordinary sequences (**not** general sequences).

But what is the difference between ordinary and general sequences? I can't find anything on the Internet

Comment: I think you mean [nets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(mathematics)). Generalised sequence is an older name for that.

Comment: And what's the difference between nets and (ordinary) sequences?

Comment: Have you read the Wikipedia link I gave? The index set can be any directed set not just $\Bbb N$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming as conjectured that "general sequence" was supposed to be "generalized sequence", ie "net":

Define a net $(x_j)_{j\in\Bbb Z}\subset\Bbb R$ by $$x_j=e^{-j}$$(where we give $\Bbb Z$ the standard order to make it a directed set). Then $x_j\to0$ but $x_j$ is not bounded.